# how to restart my own application in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, application-restart

Am working on VC++ application.

Figuring out how to restart my own application

Can somebody show some example

Comment: Its QT: but may be you find helpful [how to restart my own qt application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129788/how-to-restart-my-own-qt-application)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101391/how-to-smooth-restart-a-c-program-without-shut-down-the-running-program

Comment: If your target platform is windows. This may help to you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373524%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Write a program, which will:

- Wait for your application to terminate
- Run it again.

Call this program, then exit your application. This solution is quite widely used.

---

Another option:

Call your application with specific parameter (eg. /restarted). The new instance should wait for the old one to terminate before performing any tasks. Then shut down the old instance.

Comment: Why don't you search for this on the Internet? The C++ example doing exactly what you asked for is quite easy to find using Google.